# Applications of time series outside finance

Tags: time-series

What are some interesting application of time series outside econometrics and finance? The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series#Applications) article didn't help much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [I use time series forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1352/stephan-kolassa) to make sure your supermarket, drugstore etc. has enough product on the shelf when you come shopping.
- More generally, forecasting is big in the supply chain.
- And in all other kinds of planning for manufacturing, from planning promotions to sourcing raw materials etc.
- I just had a call about a travel agency who needs to forecast how many hotel rooms and seats on planes they need to book in advance.
- Energy companies need to forecast electricity loads and prices to plan production and hedge prices.
- Demographers need time series forecasting to tell you that we in Europe have a bleak long-range future.

You could look through the conference program of the annual [International Symposium on Forecasting](http://forecasters.org/isf/) to get an idea of interesting applications.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I gather that time spent learning time series is time spent well.

Comment: Oops. Well, thanks for accepting, but questions with *accepted* answers tend to accumulate fewer additional answers. Maybe you want to un-accept, hope for more answers and pick the best one tomorrow?

Comment: Ok, but your answer is pretty good. I don't need more answers :)